# How can I delete rows from table A and table B if rows in table B don't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, join, delete-row

I have 2 tables and I need to delete rows from both tables if A.itemID does not exist in table B 
I've tried doing : 
 DELETE  a,b
   FROM A a, B b
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM B b
                    WHERE b.cid= a.itemID
                     ); 
But I cant get the error: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'b' for update in FROM clause

All help is appreciated!

I have the following tables :

````
Table A 
+--------+--------+-------------+
|catId   | itemID | lastModified|
+--------+--------+-------------+
| 167262 | 678909 | 2017-10-01  |
| 167262 | 986785 | 2012-01-03  |
| 143210 | 456776 | 2018-04-30  |
| 143210 | 345676 | 2019-06-14  |
| 143210 | 010836 | 2016-03-09  |
| 379588 | 883567 | 2019-03-04  |
+--------+--------+-------------+
Table B 
+--------+----------+-------+
| cid    |locationid| Type  |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 678909 | 1        | a     |
| 986785 | 1        | a     |
| 143210 | 2        | b     |
| 883567 | 3        | a     |
+--------+----------+-------+ ```


My resulting tables would be :

Table A 
+--------+--------+-------------+
|catId   | itemID | lastModified|
+--------+--------+-------------+
| 167262 | 678909 | 2017-10-01  |
| 167262 | 986785 | 2012-01-03  |
| 379588 | 883567 | 2019-03-04  |

Table B
+--------+----------+-------+
| cid    |locationid| Type  |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 678909 | 1        | a     |
| 986785 | 1        | a     |
| 883567 | 3        | a     |
+--------+----------+-------+
````

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Yet another post of a faq is not "helpful".

Answer (score 1):

> I need to delete rows from both tables if A.itemID does not exist in table B

If the `itemId` does not match, then there is no row in `B`.  So, you just need to delete in `A`.  So:

```
DELETE a FROM a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM B b
                      WHERE b.cid = a.itemID
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also express your logic using a delete anti-join:

```
DELETE a
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b ON b.cid = a.itemID
WHERE b.cid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Gordon Linoff's answer (which helped me get to my solution) the following shows how to view the records that will be deleted before doing it:

To view the records that WILL be affected:

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnName FROM TableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM TableB WHERE TableB.ColumnName = TableA.ColumnName);
```

To then delete the affected rows:

```
DELETE TableA FROM TableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM TableB WHERE TableB.ColumnName = TableA.ColumnName);
```

So, the only differences are change SELECT for DELETE and removing the ColumnName from after the SELECT word.